# i want to how to setup phpunit in fuelphp?

Tags: path, phpunit, fuelphp, bootstrapping

I want to how to setup phpunit in fuelphp. I already updates my `composer.phar` after including in `composer.json` this code:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.14"
```

but when i try to test in terminal(mac osX),
it will got an error, it say:

> $ php oil
>
> Warning: require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/unishelf-web/fuel/app/app/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/unishelf-web/fuel/app/bootstrap.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/unishelf-web/fuel/app/app/config.php' (include_path='.:') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/unishelf-web/fuel/app/bootstrap.php on line 6

I try another way to, like make a dir 'phpUnit' in my web dir. i put my code there, type this command line in terminal:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit phpUnit/test/importdocumentsTest.php
```

still got error message,

> Fatal error: Class 'Input' not found

if anybody know bout this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your FuelPHP installation seems to be broken. How did you install it?

Here is how to:

```
$ curl get.fuelphp.com/oil | sh
$ oil create fuel_project
$ cd fuel_project
$ php composer.phar require phpunit/phpunit:3.7.* --dev
```

Copy `fuel/packages/oil/config/oil.php` to `fuel/app/config/`.

Edit it `'binary_path'` to

```
'binary_path' => VENDORPATH.'bin/phpunit',
```

For example, you can run FuelPHP Core tests:

```
$ oil test --group=Core
```

Comment: There is no "fuel/app/app/" directory in fuel.

Comment: i already fix it, it just need to download config.php new one. update the composer.phar and then define the path, PATH="$PWD/vendor/bin":$PATH php oil test --group=Documents.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this, this worked for me. Easiest way to obtain PHPUnit is to download a PHP Archive (PHAR).

(1) Install PHPUNIT globally

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
phpunit --version
```

(2) Copy "fuel/packages/oil/config/oil.php" to "fuel/app/config/oil.php"

(3) Change the binary path to

```
 'binary_path' => '/usr/local/bin/phpunit'
```

(4) now test your fuelphp

```
 fuelphp oil test
```